# Where should I place my respond_to block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have an `ArtcilesController` with create action like following.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => "Article created") }
      format.json { render :show }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render(:json => { :errors => @article.errors }, :status => :not_acceptable) }
    end
  end
end
```

The same action can be written like following also:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  if @article.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => "Article created") }
      format.json { render :show }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render(:json => { :errors => @article.errors }, :status => :not_acceptable) }
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that in first example there is an if else block inside of a respond_to block and in second, there are two respond_to blocks inside of a single if else block.

Should I prefer one over other? If yes, any reasons why? Or is it just a matter of choosing a style and sticking with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style only however you're only ever responding to one request and using routing logic in your controller according to your models.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { 
     @article.save ? redirect_to(@article, :notice => "Article created") : render :new
    }
    format.json { 
       @article.save ? render(:show) : render(:json => { :errors => @article.errors }, :status => :not_acceptable)
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I upvoted. Only thing I would do differently woud be to pull the @article.save out and store result in a variable. more DRY

Answer (score 0):

[respond_with](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with) in Rails 3 will DRY this up, for boilerplate code as above. It even handles rendering edit/new forms and error messages when validation fails.